# Telnet disconnected on login failure

Tags: linux, login, telnet

I have two servers running Linux 2.6.9 kernel.

When i `telnet` to server1 , the telnet will be disconnected only after 3 login failures. While, when i telnet to server2, telnet will be disconnected after the first login failure. I expect server2 to behave the same way as server1 when telnet is executed.

Kindly tell me where i should tweak my servers so that i could achieve what i expect.

Thanks,
LinuxPenseur

Comment: Hope i made my question clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem existed in the PAM configuration. While Server 1 had the correct PAM configuration, server 2 had erroneous PAM configuration.

Thanks
LinuxPenseur